# What is the second parameter of Unquote raisesWith for?

Tags: f#, f#-unquote

in the unquote [userguide](https://github.com/SwensenSoftware/unquote/wiki/UserGuide) there is an example given, which i don't understand:

```
// raisesWith : Expr -> (#exn -> Expr<bool>) -> unit
raisesWith<System.NullReferenceException> <@ ("s":string).Length @> (fun e -> <@ e.ToString() = null @>)
```

You can give a short explanation and another example ?

Answer (score 4):

You can assert on the error, as in the following example

```
raisesWith<DivideByZeroException> <@ 1/0 @> (fun e -> <@ e.Message = "Attempted to divide by zero." @>)
```